# Consider the basis $B = \{(1, 2), (3, 4)\}$. Suppose $[x]_B =(7, 11)$ for some $x \in \mathbb R^2.$ Find $x$ with respect to $\mathcal E_2.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\mathcal E_i$ denotes the standard basis.
>
> $[x]_B$ denotes the the coordinate vector with respect to the basis $B$.

$a(1, 0) + b(0, 1) = (x, y) \implies a = x, b = y$.

So, $(x, y)$ is the coordinate vector of $(x, y)$ with respect to standard basis. Since $(x, y) = (7, 11)$, we have that $(7, 11)$ is the coordinate vector of itself with respect to the standard basis.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct. $[x]_B=(a,b)$ says that $x=a.y_1+b.y_2$ where $B=\{y_1,y_2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO it's best not to think of your vectors as elements of $\Bbb R^2$ -- I just don't find there to be any motivation for change of basis in $\Bbb R^n$.  Instead just take your vectors as abstract objects which follow some easy rules and let the algebra take care of everything.

First we need to give some names to each of the four unnamed vectors in your question (two are implicit).  So let $(1,2) = [a_1]_{\mathcal E_2}$, $(3,4) = [a_2]_{\mathcal E_2}$, and the two standard basis vectors be denoted $e_1$ and $e_2$.  Then

$$[x]_B =(7, 11) \iff x = 7a_1+11a_2 \\ [a_1]_{\mathcal E_2} = (1,2) \iff a_1 = e_1 + 2e_2 \\ [a_2]_{\mathcal E_2} = (3,4) \iff a_2 = 3e_1 + 4e_2$$

Then just plugging in we get $$x = 7a_1 + 11a_2 = 7(e_1+2e_2) + 11(3e_1 + 4e_2) = 40e_1 + 58e_2 \iff \color{blue}{\require{enclose}\enclose{box}{[x]_{\mathcal E_2} = (40,58)}}$$